# Line break in qtree edge labels

Tags: line-breaking, tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree, qtree

I am using `tikz-qtree` to create a (horizontal) game tree. While I have managed to create line breaks in the node labels, this does not seem to work for the edge labels, see MWE below. My questions hence are:

1. How can I enter a line break in an edge label?
2. [answered] Both for node and edge labels: how can I keep the alignment to `left` while allowing for a line break?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right]
\tikzset{level distance=100pt, sibling distance=40pt, every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree 
    [.A
        [.B
            \edge node[auto=right, near end]{line\\ break\\ does\\ not\\ work}; D
            C
        ]
        [.{line\\ break\\ works}
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** At least for the second part, it seems that I can simply set `align=left`. I read [in this manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-qtree/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf) that one had to set it to `align=center`. The first question remains, though.

Comment: Ehm, you've answered your own question .... Add  `align=left` to the node options.

Comment: Another option is to use a predefine `text width` value for the node. As in `node[text width=2cm,....] ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered your own question: just add `align=left` to the node options, as in

```
\edge node[align=left,auto=right, near end]{line\\ break\\ does\\ not\\ work};
```

To add that to all nodes you can use the `every node` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   grow=right,
   level distance=100pt,
   sibling distance=40pt,
   every tree node/.style={anchor=north},
   every node/.append style={align=left}  % <-- added this
]
\Tree 
    [.A
        [.B
            \edge node[auto=right, near end]{line\\ break\\ does\\ work}; D
            C
        ]
        [.{line\\ break\\ works}
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```